# Oracle SQL Check Emptiness of a NUMBER data type field

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sqldatatypes

I have NUMBER(10) column "**list_id**" and wanted to check if the field is either empty or null.

So I run the following sql statement :

```
select list_id from item_list where list_id is null
```

This gave me about 200 rows where the field is totally empty (no data)

And then I run the following sql statement:

```
select count (list_id) from item_list where list_id is null
```

To my surprise this returned **count(list_id) = 0**

Is there something I am missing ? What I am trying to achieve is find those rows where the list_id is empty or null or contains no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from item_list
where list_id is null;
```

By definition, `count(<expression>)` counts the number of rows with non-`NULL` values for the expression.  This is well [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions046.htm#SQLRF00624), as well as being how `COUNT()` works in all databases:

> If you specify expr, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr
>   is not null.